# Could Pandas ever run on Spark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dask

We have a Spark cluster that is intended for performing analysis of various financial data sets in Python, ranging up to hundreds of terabytes. It works well for those comfortable with Spark but recently we've had a number of data scientists who are more familiar with Pandas requesting to use Pandas instead of Spark. The main advantage of Spark is that it is designed for distributed processing and can handle larger data sets, so we've been looking in to setting up a Dask cluster.

But it got me thinking: is there some conceptual reason why Pandas scripts could not run on a Spark cluster by implementing a compatibility layer to translate Pandas primitives into Spark primitives, the same way Dask works? Or are they fundamentally different in some way?

Comment: Considering that fundamental abstractions used by Spark and Pandas data frames (RDD and arrays respectively) are not compatible (the most of obvious difference is ordering) any translation layer would by highly limited. Furthermore common operations used with in-core pipelines, are simply not feasible at scale. So translations are possible - take a look for example at [tag:sparklyr] and might work pretty well with basic tasks, but are leaking abstractions and fail miserably with more complex requirements (ditto). Treating complex distribute system like yet another list is not a way to go...

Comment: try dask project

Comment: @user6910411 - My question is, what are those differences in fundamental abstractions? And what do you mean by ordering?

Comment: @ChitralVerma - Can you elaborate? Do you mean run Dask on Spark?

Comment: Fundamentals: a) Not random access b) No order processing guarantees for non-local (wide) operations.

Comment: @user6910411 - Thanks. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It seems that you can now do this using Databricks' new Koalas project:
https://databricks.com/blog/2019/04/24/koalas-easy-transition-from-pandas-to-apache-spark.html

Answer (score 1):

Most Spark clusters use [Apache Yarn](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) to deploy Spark across many nodes.  These clusters also use Yarn to deploy other services like Hive, Flink, Hadoop MapReduce, and so on.  Any application that can talk to Yarn is likely able to run on your cluster natively; Spark is just one such application.

You can probably run [Dask Dataframes](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) (which are today the closest thing to parallel Pandas dataframes) on your Spark/Yarn cluster today using the [Dask Yarn](https://dask-yarn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project.

Comment: This is a good idea. However, in our case we are using a cloud hosted version of Spark, so unfortunately won't have access to Yarn.